# Unable to select AppCompat theme for Android Studio Design view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-layout-editor

AppCompat theme is selected as following:
[image]

The outcome is Material Light as following:
[image]

The layout file is a fragment of an Android library project.  Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I just found a solution myself - turned out I had an error in my `AndroidManifest.xml` for the activity I was trying to preview... Didn't get any error messages anywhere and it compiled just fine - but in fact I had a closing `>` before the line where I was declaring the theme to use for the activity.